# How to get all potential routes in c-lightning?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, core-lightning

I'm trying to write some services on top of c-lightning and I need to check if certain payments hit certain nodes.

> lightning-cli getroute nodeid amount riskfactor

This gives me a randomly selected single route out of potential two routes.

Is it possible for me to get all potential routes and decide for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you invest some programming time you can use the `listchannels` command to retrieve all channels of the lightning network from the gossip store. No you could store them in the `networkx` lib

```
import networkx as nx
network = ln.listchannels()
nx.Graph()                                                                                                                 
for channel in network:                                                                                                        
    G.add_edge(channel["source"],                                                                                              
               channel["destination"],                                                                                         
               **channel)
```

and then you could use [this algorithm](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths) from the networkx library to get a generator for all paths between a source and a destination rout. Since the lightning network will most likely have cycles you need to define a cutoff. While 20 is to long from a computational point of view it is also the [the maximum path length an onion packet supports according to BOLT 04](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/04-onion-routing.md#conventions).

> Length: the maximum route length is limited to 20 hops.